# Rear brake not working motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, brakes

So I changed the brake fluid on both brakes on my motorcycle and now the rear just slips. I can feel the break 'grab' in the pedal but the brake disc just slips right through.
Now I did end up getting brake fluid on the disc and a small bit on the pads. 
I did clean both with warm water and washing up liquid.
What would be advised?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You haven't cleaned the parts well enough by just using warm water and washing up liquid. You can clean the disk by using brake cleaner and a clean cloth. The pads on the other hand, should be replaced. You can get most of the brake fluid off of them, but they are most likely ruined now and will never give you full performance. Only by replacement are you sure of full performance and therefore full safety of the brakes.

Comment: awesome so new pads and clean disc with brake cleaner and I should be good? Just as I suspected. How does the fluid ruin the pads? I do have new pads on the way and brake cleaner.

Comment: The material of the pads absorbs the brake fluid - which is much more chemically active than water, so putting brake fluid on pads means you need to change them.

Comment: I see, the pads will be changed when the new ones arrive hopefully tomorrow. Also there is a click noise when pushing the pedal that was never there before. Can this be related to the fluid on the pads?

Comment: @DamoC - I wouldn't think so. As far as the new pads, make sure you clean the rotor surface again when you take the old pads off to ensure you don't contaminate your new pads.

Comment: Thank you, hopefully pads will be here tomorrow, I got the brake cleaner picked up today.